# How to prove grammar safe for SLL

Tags: antlr4

I have an antlr4 grammar that takes a very long time to parse long expressions like `f()()()()...()()()` due to superlinear runtime of the predictor.  The expression rule also has the usual set of arithmetic-like operators with different precedences.  I can cut runtime down to a reasonable level by switching to SLL mode.  My problem is, a significant fraction of input programs will have parse errors. I have to retry with LL to distinguish real errors from spurious errors generated by the less powerful parser.  That means average performance will still be poor.

How can I tell if a grammar is safe to parse in SLL mode, without retrying in LL?

Are there any general tricks to rewriting a grammar so long expressions can be parsed less slowly?